# Something wrong with ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()

Tags: python, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I'm recently started to use python with mobile app automation, as i decided to use python, the main instruments that I've found were monkeyrunner and androidviewclient.

But there is the first issue with which i dont know what to do:

```
package = 'com.mypackage.android'
activity = '.launchActivity'
component = package + "/" + activity

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.startActivity(component=component)


time.sleep(3)

vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
vc.dump()

showMenu = vc.findViewById("id/no_id/8")
showMenu.touch()
```

as i'm running it in windows cmd - monkeyrunner mypath\test-case1.py
i receive an exception:

```
131213 18:42:32.555:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
131213 18:42:32.555:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\tests\1.py", line 26, in <module>
    device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient-maste
r\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1381, in conne
ctToDeviceOrExit
    ViewClient.setAlarm(timeout+5)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient-maste
r\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1341, in setAl
arm
    signal.alarm(timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\jython-standalone-2
.5.3.jar\Lib\signal.py", line 222, in alarm
NotImplementedError: alarm not implemented on this platform
```

am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Which *AndroidViewClient* version are you using?
There's no `alarm` in Windows, this might be one of the problems.

Comment: I'm using te latest one, I've downloaded it yesterday from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `setAlarm` looks like

```
@staticmethod
def setAlarm(timeout):
    osName = platform.system()
    if osName.startswith('Windows'): # alarm is not implemented in Windows
        return
    signal.alarm(timeout)
```

so, it tries to identify that is Windows and then not invoking `signal.alarm()` which is not implemented, but for some reason it fails in your case.
Try to print the result of `osName` to see what went wrong.

### UPDATE

Now I see, you are using `monkeyrunner` as the interpreter but *AndroidViewClient >= 4.0.0* is 100% pure python, so you should run your scripts using a `python` 2.x interpreter.

Comment: `>>> import platform >>> osName = platform.system() >>> print osName` output:Windows So it's Windows

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working, using with python 2.7 interpreter was the right solution. Is it working with python 3.x versions?